# Mysql array to json convertion

Tags: php, mysql, json

i have a question i have tryied to make an json response to look like that:

```
{

"0":{
    "cid":"2",
    "user_name":"4",
    "user_title":null,
    "user_description":null,
    "user_tags":null,
    "user_imgid_logo":"05d419b4cc5c6d1d2fabf90a8dbd967a",
    "user_online":"2",
    "rank":"0",
    "multibitrate":"0",
    "user_name":"gqgeee",
    "user_logo_url":"http:\/\/static.example.tv\/logos\/05d419b4cc5c6d1d2fabf90a8dbd967a.jpg",
    "user_image":"1"
},
"1":{
    "cid":"1434",
    "user_name":"dokumenty",
    "user_title":"*Filmy dokumentalne* (^HQ^-^HD^)",
    "user_description":"short deskt",
    "user_tags":"asfasf",
    "user_imgid_logo":"51bbe341fe3e92f37a89609b80274be8",
    "user_online":"2",
    "rank":"1",
    "multibitrate":"1",
    "user_name":"asdd",
    "user_logo_url":"http:\/\/static.example.tv\/logos\/51bbe341fe3e92f37a89609b80274be8.jpg",
    "user_image":"1"
}}
```

I have managed to connect to mysql, and create json from database but my json doesnt look as one above:

```
[

{
    "1":{
        "cid":"1",
        "user_name":"sgsd",
        "user_title":"sgsd asgx",
        "user_description":"asgx na czasie",
        "user_tags":"asgx",
        "user_imgid_logo":"sgsd",
        "user_online":"2",
        "rank":"3",
        "multibitrate":"1",
        "user_name":"Kowalski",
        "user_logo_url":"http:\/\/upload.wikimedia.org\/wikipedia\/commons\/8\/84\/asd.png",
        "user_image":"1"
    }
},
{
    "2":{
        "cid":"2",
        "user_name":"sgsd 2",
        "user_title":"sgsd asgx 2",
        "user_description":"asgx na czasie 2",
        "user_tags":"asgx",
        "user_imgid_logo":"sgsd",
        "user_online":"2",
        "rank":"3",
        "multibitrate":"1",
        "user_name":"Kowalski",
        "user_logo_url":"http:\/\/upload.wikimedia.org\/wikipedia\/commons\/8\/84\/sgsd.tv_logo_2014.png",
        "user_image":"1"
    }
}

]
```

^ brackets are not needed and json still is messed up a bit.

this is my souce code of php:

```
<?php
$getoption = $_GET["option"];
if ($getoption === 'psd') {
//$dataList = substr($dataList, 1, -1);
//open connection to mysql db
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","datbase","duser","upass") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($connection));
//fetch table rows from mysql db
$sql = "select * from public";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die("Error in Selecting " . mysqli_error($connection));
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
//create an array
//    $emparray[] = array();
//$emparray[] = array('1'=>$row);
echo '<pre>';
var_dump(mysqli_fetch_assoc($result));
echo '</pre>';
$start = 1;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
$emparray[] = array($start=>array($row));
$start++;
}
//$dataList = substr(json_encode($emparray), 1, -1);
$dataList = json_encode($emparray);
echo $dataList;
//close the db connection
mysqli_close($connection);
}
if ($getoption === 'sk') {
echo 'ks os';
}
?>
```

Would any body willing to help? Thanks.

Comment: if you are seeing [ ] around { }, it is correct. your front end JS ajax call will be able to read it properly. =)

at the front end, make sure that it treats the json response as an array instead of an object.

Comment: try `json_encode($amparray, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT)`

Comment: to validate any json you can check here http://jsonlint.org

Comment: You are using a multi dimensional array, so it is nothing but the array of object that you can easily loop through in jquery. Do not forget to parse the json before looping through it.

Comment: Thanks all of You, combining all of your answers and tips managed to make it working, i needed to encode it as an object thanks pala_ and Arcanyx for good point of creating correct array structure!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$start = 1;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
$emparray[$start] = $row;
$start++;
}
$dataList = json_encode($emparray);
echo $dataList;
```

Try this!! Mostly the part inside the while loop is a bit messed up.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with this...

```
$start = 0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $emparray[] = array($start=>$row);
    $start++;
 }
```